# how to align bootstrap navbar in center of my website

Tags: navigation

` **http://tansoosuan.com/tss02/performance.html**

Toggle navigation

PERFORMANCE

DISCOVER YOUR VOICE

RECORDING

COMMUNITY LOVE

`

Comment: Please post the relevant code to your question. See the [ask] page for help